# NodeJS application structure - services

Tags: node.js, web-applications

Express application. MVC structure. The question is: should I or I should not merge services with the application ? My services are a chat service and a mail service. I'am using node-imap to retrive some emails and store them in the database. Express application query that database(along other things) and show them to the user.

I did not created the chat service yet but the email service is on development, and now I'm at crossroads: should I start this mail service in a new instance of nodejs or should I integrate it with the main express application ?

MORE INFO:

Having that email service running in his own nodejs instance is usefull for dealing with service fails. So if there was a problem I don't need to restart my entire application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it comes down to scalability.  If you're going to be the only one who maintains it, then it doesn't really matter.  If you're working with a team and this is a product you're going to continue developing on I would suggest breaking them out into independent services that rely on each other, but can be maintained, troubleshot, and upgraded independently.

I'm a big fan of agile and lean development, so the idea of putting multiple small things out there sounds great.  It allows for future small changes.

Comment: Let's say that my `mail service` will have nothing to do with my `main app`. How can I transfer information from `mail service` to `main app` ? I mean If I want to keep track of last date when messages were fetched and use them in `main app` how should I do? If I create a web server just for a GET it would be useless.